# Empty Payload Lambda Step Function

Tags: lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a stepfunction that executes a a series of lambdas where output from one will be input to the next. Now I am trying to get it work with only the first lambda individually first. However, the Payload output is empty {}. This is the step function definition:

```json
{
"Comment": "A description of my state machine",
"StartAt": "GetCharge",
"States": {
"GetCharge": {
"Type": "Task",
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
"OutputPath": "$.Payload",
"Parameters": {
"Payload.$": "$",
"FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:130626555560:function:GetChargeLambda:$LATEST"
},
"Retry": [
{
"ErrorEquals": [
"Lambda.ServiceException",
"Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
"Lambda.SdkClientException"
],
"IntervalSeconds": 2,
"MaxAttempts": 6,
"BackoffRate": 2
}
],
"End": true
}
}
}
```

The input to the lambda looks like this:

```json
{
  "operationType": "Charge.get",
  "charge": {
    "id": "some_value"
  }
}
```

The part that blows my mind is that GetChargeLambda returns a `GetChargeResponse` object. However, if I change it so that it simply returns a `Charge`, which is a field of `GetChargeResponse` then the exact same step function definition works. My only logical explanation is that there is something off with the serialization of `GetChargeResponse`???

Comment: The OP refers to named types but does not define them, so it's a wee bit confusing.  In any case, I would expect that changing `"OutputPath": "$.Payload"` to `"OutputPath": "$.charge"` produces task output like `{ "id": "some_value" }`.  Is that what is happening?

Comment: But when I return `Charge` instead then it works fine. When I do the suggested change the Lambda executes fine but the step function get cancelled.

Comment: You keep refering to some undefined types like `Charge` and `GetChargeResponse`.  You know what these are, but we don't!  Please edit the question with a problem statement expressed in JSON. Remember that the JSON is case-sensitive, so being explicit is important.